# Streaming not working when adding uwsgi in between python ngnix

Tags: django, streaming, uwsgi, uwsgi-stats-server

I'm developing a chat application that streams messages, and it functions well when I access the UI directly through Django on my local environment. It also works when I have the following setup:

Python server <-> Nginx

However, when I introduce uWSGI into the configuration, the response streaming stops, and I receive the response all at once. I've tried various solutions, but none have resolved the issue. Can you provide guidance on how to correct this problem?

Python server <-> uwsgi <-> Nginx

Streaming should work as expected. I tried to reduce buffer but didnt work